# Combine two dimensions on google data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have two dimensions but similar data in two differents columns on my google sheet and in my google data studio report, for example, "Organizations type 1", and "Organizations type 2". It's possible combine this two dimension on one, like "Organizations"?
Greetings for everyone and thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 1):

A solution for me was to create a new calculated dimension 'Organizations' like this:

`CASE
WHEN Organizations type 1 is null THEN Organizations type 2
WHEN Organizations type 2 is null THEN Organizations type 1
END`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a calculated field and use the function concatenate to combine the two dimensions (columns) into one.

Answer (score -2):

You can resolve this issue using Google Sheets with these simple steps:

**Step 1**: Connect your GA4 data to a Google Sheet using the **GA4 - Reporting for Google Analytics 4** add-on.

**Step 2**: Link your GA4 property and select the dimensions you want to merge.

**Step 3**: If you want to merge data from columns A, B, C, and D, starting from the 2nd row (A2, B2, C2, D2), type the following formula in an empty column:

```
=UNIQUE({A2:A;B2:B;C2:C;D2:D})
```

This will combine your data into a single column.

**Step 4**: Connect this sheet with your Looker Studio and choose the dimension from the combined data column.

For a more detailed explanation, refer to the video below.:

[In looker studio, combining multiple dimensions into one](https://youtu.be/7poOfWxUTCc?si=pY3pBayB-nN7dZl6)